# How to send a call and wait for response effectively in compact framework?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, compact-framework

If you need to send a call (For **e.g**: to a COM Port) which executes in another thread and sends you the result back, then the called thread should wait until the parallel thread completes its operation.

If you use `while(boolflag)` then it becomes a thread intensive operation, where it will loops into the same statement, until the flag is set, making the program to allocate more resources and sooner you will get into some memory management issues in case of a Multi-threaded application where it runs many While loop waits.

.Net4.0 has Async/Await to execute the tasks asynchronously and return the result when its completed. But in CF 3.5 its not available.

Below is the solution to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**To wait effectively without spending any more resources**, CF 3.5 provides `ManualResetEvent/AutoResetEvent` (ManualResetEvent provides more control over the reset event and hence most recommended to be used).

Declare a ManualResetEvent

```
private ManualResetEvent m_ManualWaitForResponse;
```

And in the caller method, which will send the call to another thread to execute some process and returns the result,

1.First Reset the event.

2.Then after sending the *other thread* call wait for the response, until the other thread sets the event.

```
private void SendAndWaitForResponse(string command)
{
       m_ManualWaitForResponse.Reset();
       m_objComm.SendString(m_LastCommandSent);
       m_Timer.Change(CScaleServer.constTWOSECOND, 0);
       m_ManualWaitForResponse.WaitOne();
}
```

The *other thread* sets the event once the job is done.

```
m_ManualWaitForResponse.Set()
```

In the 3rd line of the above code sample, you can see a `Timer` which runs after 2 seconds of due time. This is for safety purpose to set the same event within the timer if no response is received from the other thread due to some COM connection issues (or) if no command is sent to COM and the parent thread is waiting indefinitely.

*The Timer code:*

```
private void eventOnTimer(object StateInfo)
{
      m_ManualWaitForResponse.Set()
}
```

Comment: Note that the waiting thread is blocked, so you still waste some resources

Comment: Yes but not to the level of usung while loops to wait indefenitely executing something and wasting resource. Cf 3.5 doent have Tasks to do an async work and return the results asynchronously. Absolutely the thread has to wait until it gets the result. It is based upon the choice of implementation depending upon the scenario.

Comment: Yeah, I understand, Just noted that it's worth to switch the .Net framework, as it is already not supported

Comment: Yeah but that cannot be done in CE6.0 or WEC7 which is created for compact version of windows OS. So one who uses it can be benefitted.